# Seemingly circular definition of a collection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, foundations

In the book I'm reading on set theory right now, I'm given this definition:

"If $\Phi(x)$ is a formula then the term $\iota !y(\forall x)(x\in y\iff \Phi(x))$ is abbreviated $\{x:\Phi(x)\}$ and read 'the collection of all $x$ such that $\Phi(x)$'."

Later, it is stated that:

"We have defined 'collection of...' but not 'collection'...The naive idea is that collections are precisely objects of the form $\{x:\Phi(x)\}$ for some formula $\Phi(x)$. This does not work under the formal restrictions we imposed in the Introduction. [Only first order logic] Instead:

We say that $a$ is a collection if $a=\{x:x\in a\}$".

Now maybe I'm misreading this, but it appears to me that the definition of a collection as shown here is circular. It seems that we have "$a$ is a collection if it is the collection of all $x$ that belong to $a$"...which is not at all illuminating.

Am I misreading this?

Comment: What's $\iota$ in this context? And what book are you reading?

Comment: It is read as "the definite", so $\exists \iota x(\Phi(x))$ is read as "there exists a definite $x$ such that $\Phi$ holds for $x$".

Comment: "Sets : An introduction", by Michael D. Potter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My references are to the revised edition :

- Michael Potter, [Set Theory and its Philosophy](https://books.google.it/books?id=FxRoPuPbGgUC&printsec=frontcover) (2004).

---

Potter has "revived" the (not very usual today) treatment of set theory with individuals or *atoms* (also called : *ur-elements*).

Loosly speaking, *atoms* are objects of the domain of the interpretation that can be members of *collection* but that has no memebers, i.e. if$x$ is an *atom*, then for **no** $y$ we have $y \in x$.

We need a "relativizing" predicate $U(x)$, meaning : $x$ is an individual (or *atom*).

Thus we have the definition [page 24] of "collection of $\Phi$'s", for a first-order formula $\Phi(x)$ :

> the *term* $\iota ! y(\lnot U(y) \land (\forall x)( x \in y \Leftrightarrow \Phi(x)))$ is abbreviated $\{ x : \Phi(x) \}$ and we read it as "the *collection of* all $x$ such that $\Phi(x)$" (if it exists).

Then we have [page 30] the definition :

> we say that $b$ is a *collection* if $b = \{ x : x \in b \}$.

We have to "unwind" the defining formula, noting that, in this case, the f-o formula $\Phi(x)$ is $x \in b$ :

> $b = \iota ! y(\lnot U(y) \land (\forall x)( x \in b \Leftrightarrow x \in b))$.

But $\vdash (\forall x)( x \in b \Leftrightarrow x \in b)$ and thus, by logic alone, we have that the seemingly "circular" definition simply amounts to saying that:

> > $b$ is a *collection* iff $b = \iota ! y(\lnot U(y))$

i.e. : $b$ is a *collection* if it is not an individual, as you can see from the following :

> (2.6.1) **Lemma**. No collection is an individual.

Comment: Ah, that's much better than what was written. I made the connection that the first sentence I put up there was simply about a term that informally was described as a collection until it could be proven that it was a collection whenever it existed.

Comment: You say his approach is not very common today, what is a good book that I can use to self teach whatever the more common view is? At the same time a good book on logic might be nice to have.

Comment: @Nethesis - alot of good books on logic : Peter Smith, [An Introduction to Formal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=bX91C6GOBkcC&printsec=frontcover), Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&printsec=frontcover), Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: There are also lots of good books on set theory : Derek Goldrei, [Classic Set Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=1dLn0knvZSsC&printsec=frontcover), Robert Vaught, [Set Theory: An Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=sqxKHEwb5FkC&printsec=frontcover), Ralf Schindler, [Set Theory: Exploring Independence and Truth](https://books.google.it/books?id=5TcqBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: I haven't read Ralf's book (in fact, your comment was the first time I've heard that he had one; but it's quite new so it's not surprising). If he writes like he lectures, the book should be pretty good. But it might not be suitable for beginners.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - I agree (but I've only browsed the first chapters ...). My intention was to point at some new textbook; if I remember well, in some of your comments you suggested a recent one (not Jech nor Kunen), but I'm not able to remember it...

Comment: Halbeisen's Combinatorial Set Theory?